# How to start JavaFX scene in a new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to start a new scene from my main scene in a new thread.

Here is my action button:

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new OpenScene());
        t1.start();
```

OpenScene Class with implements Runnable

```
public class OpenConsole implements Runnable {   
       @Override
            public void run() {
                  System.out.println("hello from run");
                try {

                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLConsole.fxml"));

                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                    stage.showAndWait();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }         


}
```

I am able to print a statement from run, but I don't see a new scene/stage.

Comment: I don't know JavaFX. But normally, like android and opengl, there is only one thread that can handle all graphical interface. I would not be surprised if JavaFX works at the same way.

Comment: Have you tried `Platform.runLater(new OpenScene())`?

Comment: No I haven't, let me look into that. if this is the solution, please add it as an answer. Thanks!